# Query runs a long time in some newer MySQL versions

Tags: mysql, innodb, mysql-5.5, mysql-5.1, mysql-5.0

I have created a database on MySQL 5.0.15. I have a query and when I run this query on this MySQL version, I get 0.9 s run time. When I import this database to another MySQL server with same hardware and run the same query I get over 120s and sometimes MySQL hangs.

What is the difference between 5.0 and 5.1 or 5.5? I have tested 5.1 and 5.5 versions.

Is it possible a query takes longer in a newer version (something like mysql structure change)?

Sorry but I can't put this query here, but the query is like:

```
SELECT fl_passenger_ticket. *, 
       fl_aganc.name                             AS agancname, 
       fl_pnr.remark                             AS remark, 
       fl_pnr.reservetime                        AS reservetime, 
       fl_pnr.cancelpnr, 
       fl_flight_date.fromcity                   AS fromcity, 
       fl_flight_date.tocity                     AS tocity, 
       fl_flight_date.flightdate                 AS flightdate, 
       fl_flightdate_capacity.adultper           AS adultper, 
       fl_flightdate_capacity.childper           AS childper, 
       fl_flightdate_capacity.infantper          AS infantper, 
       fl_flightdate_capacity.cancel             AS cancelsegment, 
       fl_flightdate_capacity.tax1adultpric, 
       fl_flightdate_capacity.tax1childpric, 
       fl_flightdate_capacity.tax1infantpric, 
       fl_flightdate_capacity.tax2adultpric, 
       fl_flightdate_capacity.tax2childpric, 
       fl_flightdate_capacity.tax2infantpric, 
       ( fl_flightdate_capacity.tax3adultpric + 
         fl_flightdate_capacity.tax4adultpric + 
         fl_flightdate_capacity.tax5adultpric )  AS taxxtadultpric, 
       ( fl_flightdate_capacity.tax3childpric + 
         fl_flightdate_capacity.tax4childpric + 
         fl_flightdate_capacity.tax5childpric )  AS taxxtchildpric, 
       ( fl_flightdate_capacity.tax3infantpric + 
         fl_flightdate_capacity.tax4infantpric 
         + 
         fl_flightdate_capacity.tax5infantpric ) AS taxxtinfantpric 
FROM   fl_passenger_ticket 
       INNER JOIN fl_pnr 
         ON ( fl_passenger_ticket.pnrid = fl_pnr.pnrid ) 
       INNER JOIN fl_aganc 
         ON ( fl_pnr.agancid = fl_aganc.agancid ) 
       LEFT JOIN fl_flightdate_capacity 
         ON ( fl_pnr.pnrid = fl_flightdate_capacity.pnrid ) 
       LEFT JOIN fl_flight_date 
         ON ( fl_flightdate_capacity.flightdateid = fl_flight_date.flightdateid 
            ) 
WHERE  fl_passenger_ticket.ticketnumber <> '' 
       AND fl_passenger_ticket.pnrid <> 0 
       AND fl_pnr.agancid = 60 
       AND fl_flightdate_capacity.aganccharterid = 0 
       AND fl_flightdate_capacity.cancel IN ( 0, 1 ) 
       AND fl_pnr.reservetime >= '2011/09/01 00:00:00' 
       AND fl_pnr.reservetime <= '2011/09/19 23:59:00' 
ORDER  BY fl_passenger_ticket.rowid, 
          fl_pnr.reservetime
```

- I have 4 joins.
- The table is innodb.
- There are 100000 records

The result is 100 rows and 50 columns.

EXPLAIN result is
[image]

show variables like 'innodb%' result

[image]

Comment: The first things I'll mention. Can you post the EXPLAIN output? `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`. Next, verify the configuration of the new server is similar to the old server as far as innodb settings go.. `innodb_buffer_pool` for starters. Is the hardware similar (amount of RAM specifically)? Please add the answers to the question, if you would.

Comment: where do check innodb_buffer_pool? hardware is same.

Comment: humm, I wouldn't point mysql version as the cause of this discrepant behavior since the difference is too noticeable. When you say another mysql server, you mean just another version of mysql or another hardware server?

Comment: i mean mysql version

Comment: @av `show variables like 'innodb%'` should help.

Comment: how does that output compare to the 5.0 version? What is the data size of your innodb tables? If it's bigger than 15MB, you should increase innodb_buffer_pool_size (requires access to the my.cnf and server restart)

Comment: inno db table related to query 5MB. i add mysql version 5 result soon. what shoud innodb_buffer_pool_size  be?

Comment: Are the table indexes all intact in the restored database? I have a feeling involving indexation.

Comment: @av See innodb portion of [this answer](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/6038/extreme-storage-beasts/6039#6039) to calculate the size of your innodb_buffer_pool, with caveat that it shouldn't be more than 80% of your available memory...Allow for growth, but it looks like you don't need to touch it.

Comment: i update my question with original query. table havent any index. plz check my query for performance.

Comment: Why the LEFT JOIN on fl_flightdate_capacity when there are two conditions in the WHERE? That makes it an INNER JOIN. Or you should make it part of the join condition

Comment: Have you already compared both server configurations or checked what @DTest suggested?

Comment: at last with index i have 0.2s run time in mysql 5.1. but without index run time is 120s.then  why without index mysql 5.0 has a good run time?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just off the bat, newer versions of MySQL actually improve innodb performance (especially 5.5). I would highly recommend updating to this version if you're going to run InnoDB.

One method you could use to hunt down why it's taking so much longer is using [MySQL Profiles](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-profiles.html)

```
mysql> SET PROFILING=1;
mysql> SHOW TABLES;
mysql> SELECT * FROM foo;
mysql> SET PROFILING=0;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SHOW PROFILES;
+----------+------------+-------------------+
| Query_ID | Duration   | Query             |
+----------+------------+-------------------+
|        1 | 0.09270400 | SHOW TABLES       |
|        2 | 0.00026400 | SELECT * FROM foo |
+----------+------------+-------------------+
2 rows in set (0.05 sec)

mysql> SHOW PROFILE FOR QUERY 2;
+----------------------+----------+
| Status               | Duration |
+----------------------+----------+
| starting             | 0.000053 |
| checking permissions | 0.000009 |
| Opening tables       | 0.000032 |
| System lock          | 0.000010 |
| init                 | 0.000028 |
| optimizing           | 0.000003 |
| statistics           | 0.000012 |
| preparing            | 0.000008 |
| executing            | 0.000003 |
| Sending data         | 0.000068 |
| end                  | 0.000004 |
| query end            | 0.000007 |
| closing tables       | 0.000008 |
| freeing items        | 0.000013 |
| logging slow query   | 0.000003 |
| cleaning up          | 0.000003 |
+----------------------+----------+
16 rows in set (0.04 sec)
```

This should give you an indication of where it's hanging. From your explain output, you should try to get some indexing on the second and third tables instead of doing full table scans. But without DDL or the actual join columns, I can't suggest anything better than to research indexing strategies.

Comment: thank u.with "some indexing on the second and third tables" i got under 1 s run time. but what about mysql 5.0 and good run time without index?

Comment: @av First place I'd look is at your tmp_table_size and max_heap_table_size (the lesser of the 2 is the limit). If it your temporary table doesn't fit in amount specified by those values, it will create an on-disk temporary table.

Answer (score 8):

Using MySQL 5.5 out-of-the-box without proper configuration is [like getting a Lamborghini and expecting topnotch performance on a gallon of regular gasoline (87 Octane).](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Lamborghini_22PS_1951.jpg)

You should expect [better performance with high octane gasoline in a Lamborghini](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Lotus-Lamborghini_102.jpg).

As with any database product, it is only as performance-enhanced as you actually configure it. [Just like Spiderman said (8:36 - 8:40) : "WITH GREAT POWER, THERE MUST ALSO ALWAYS BE GREAT RESPONSIBILITY"](http://youtu.be/GH5mTcr0uH0).

To get better performance out of MySQL 5.5, you must honestly configure certain things.

- OPTION 1 : [**Use separate tablespace files for InnoDB, separating data and index pages from ibdata1**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3927690/howto-clean-a-mysql-innodb-storage-engine/4056261#4056261)
- OPTION 2 : [**Configure options that engage more CPUs**](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/5666/possible-to-make-mysql-use-more-then-one-core/5670#5670)
- OPTION 3 : [**Increase the number of threads dedicated for reads and writes**](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/5926/multi-cores-and-mysql-performance/5968#5968)
- OPTION 4 : [**Properly tune InnoDB Options**](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/2918/about-single-threaded-versus-multithreaded-databases-performance/2948#2948)
- OPTION 5 : [**Size your InnoDB Buffer Pool so it is large enough to hold all data, or 75% of installed RAM, whichever is smaller**](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1/what-are-the-main-differences-between-innodb-and-myisam/2194#2194).
- OPTION 6 : [**Use O_DIRECT for InnoDB Flushing**](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1568/clarification-on-mysql-innodb-flush-method-variable/1575#1575)
- OPTION 7 : Use a dedicated DB Server, apart from LAMP, WAMP, XAMPP, Munin, and software like these.