# MariaDB XtraDB Performance Tuning

Tags: mysql, performance, innodb, mariadb, xtradb

I believe that innodb has a single read thread. However, with MariaDB you can set multiple read threads. I'm unsure what the recommended value would be.

Questions

- Does anyone have any experience with MariaDB and performance tuning?
- Can you think of any features within MariaDB that XtraDB uses that MySQL does not?
- Are there any similar settings that can I can use to fully exploit XtraDB and Maria's enhanced functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

InnoDB in Percona Server 5.0.91 and MySQL 5.5.x has three options

- [innodb_read_io_threads](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_read_io_threads)
- [innodb_write_io_threads](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_write_io_threads)
- [innodb_io_capacity](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_io_capacity)

These options were introduced in MySQL 5.1.38 InnoDB Plugin

Tuning these will engage more CPUs within InnoDB/XtraDB

I have discussed this in past posts in the DBA StackExchange along with other InnoDB tuning suggestions

- [Multi cores and MySQL Performance](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/5926/multi-cores-and-mysql-performance/5968#5968)
- [About single threaded versus multithreaded databases performance](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/2918/about-single-threaded-versus-multithreaded-databases-performance/2948#2948)
- [Possible to make MySQL use more than one core?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/5666/possible-to-make-mysql-use-more-then-one-core/5670#5670)
- [Query runs a long time in some newer MySQL versions](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/6526/query-runs-a-long-time-in-some-newer-mysql-versions/6542#6542)

[**Click here**](http://www.percona.com/docs/wiki/percona-xtradb:features:start) for the XtraDB features that the InnoDB Plugin does not have.