# Frequently slow queries while in the 'Update' state

Tags: mysql, replication, performance, innodb

I have two tables that I update very frequently, one with a direct `UPDATE ..` and another `INSERT .. ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...` Normally these queries are instant but at times will take 0.1s to 1+ seconds and then be instant again for a few seconds.

Another thing to note, I have two MySQL servers (in the same private network). All select queries (barring one or two) are executed on the slave and the inserts seen here are of course on the master. The slowdowns are most apparent when the database is under a large load. Lastly, I am using xtradb (to see if it helped) but the same behaviour occurred while on just plain MySQL 5.5 InnoDB.

```
-- CustomData
+-----------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field     | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Server    | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| Plugin    | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| ColumnID  | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| DataPoint | int(11) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| Updated   | int(11) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
+-----------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Ex. of a couple queries:

```
mysql> insert into CustomData (Server, Plugin, ColumnID, DataPoint, Updated) VALUES ( 52707, 1, 1, 0, 1327093596) on duplicate key update DataPoint = 0 , Updated = 1327093596 ;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> insert into CustomData (Server, Plugin, ColumnID, DataPoint, Updated) VALUES ( 52707, 1, 1, 0, 1327093596) on duplicate key update DataPoint = 0 , Updated = 1327093596 ;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.12 sec)

mysql> insert into CustomData (Server, Plugin, ColumnID, DataPoint, Updated) VALUES ( 52707, 1, 1, 0, 1327093596) on duplicate key update DataPoint = 0 , Updated = 1327093596 ;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> insert into CustomData (Server, Plugin, ColumnID, DataPoint, Updated) VALUES ( 52707, 1, 1, 0, 1327093596) on duplicate key update DataPoint = 0 , Updated = 1327093596 ;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

EXPLAIN-

```
mysql> explain select * from CustomData where Server = 52707 and Plugin = 1 and ColumnID = 1 ;
+----+-------------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+-------------------+------+-------+
| id | select_type | table      | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref               | rows | Extra |
+----+-------------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+-------------------+------+-------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | CustomData | const | PRIMARY,Cron  | PRIMARY | 12      | const,const,const |    1 |       |
+----+-------------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+-------------------+------+-------+
```

Profiler (for the 0.12 sec query)

```
mysql> show profile for query 56 ;
+----------------------+----------+
| Status               | Duration |
+----------------------+----------+
| starting             | 0.000062 |
| checking permissions | 0.000005 |
| Opening tables       | 0.000016 |
| System lock          | 0.000007 |
| init                 | 0.000011 |
| update               | 0.129531 |
| end                  | 0.000005 |
| query end            | 0.000012 |
| closing tables       | 0.000008 |
| freeing items        | 0.000017 |
| logging slow query   | 0.000001 |
| cleaning up          | 0.000036 |
+----------------------+----------+
```

All other problematic queries are very similar. I don't notice any long-running queries in `show processlist;`

SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS (need 10 rep to post >2 links, so)-
pastebin .com/raw.php?i=tdtZeTCJ

One last thing I would like to note, that in the given example, any worker only ever executes an `INSERT .. ON DUPLICATE KEY` on a unique row, not the same row (so each query is for a different row)

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**

All of my data is around 3G with indexes. Buffer pool size was 2G at first but have tried 4G as well.

my.cnf-

```
[mysqld]
datadir = /data/mysql
socket = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
user = mysql
bind-address = 10.10.1.7

log-slow-queries = mysql-slow.log
long_query_time = 5
log-queries-not-using-indexes

# Replication
server-id        = 1

# master
log-bin          = /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log
expire-logs-days = 10
binlog-do-db     = metrics
max_binlog_size  = 104857600
binlog_format    = MIXED

# slave
# replicate-do-db  = metrics
# read_only        = 1

# /Replication

skip-external-locking
sysdate-is-now

performance_schema

log-error=/var/log/mysql.log

default-storage-engine          = InnoDB

innodb_file_per_table           = 1
innodb_file_format              = barracuda

innodb_buffer_pool_size          = 4G
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size  = 10M
innodb_log_buffer_size           = 8M
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit   = 0
innodb_lock_wait_timeout         = 50
innodb_fast_shutdown             = 1
innodb_flush_method              = O_DIRECT
transaction_isolation            = READ-COMMITTED

max_connections                 = 4092
connect_timeout                 = 86400
wait_timeout                    = 86400
interactive_timeout             = 86400
max_allowed_packet              = 64M

open_files_limit                = 2048
table_cache                     = 2048
net_buffer_length               = 8K
query_cache_type                = 1
query_cache_size                = 16M
thread_cache                    = 100
thread_stack                    = 512K
tmpdir                          = /dev/shm
tmp_table_size                  = 64M

key_buffer_size                 = 64M
sort_buffer_size                = 512K
net_buffer_length               = 8K
read_buffer_size                = 256K
read_rnd_buffer_size            = 512K
myisam_sort_buffer_size         = 8M

[mysqldump]
quick
max_allowed_packet              = 16M
[mysql]
no-auto-rehash

[myisamchk]
key_buffer_size                 = 20M
sort_buffer_size                = 20M
read_buffer                     = 2M
write_buffer                    = 2M

[mysqlhotcopy]
interactive-timeout

[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
```

**EDIT2**

innotop-

[one](http://img.griefcraft.com/19571de) [two](http://img.griefcraft.com/74ff8de)

I read about gap locking - is it possible that it is gap locking my `Plugin` and `ColumnID` columns, ignoring the fact that the PK is 3 cols and also the fact that I am using READ-COMMITTED so it shouldn't be anyway ? As can be seen in innotop, some are these are very close so if this is the case then there will be a lot of locks going around

```
mysql> show indexes from CustomData;
+------------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table      | Non_unique | Key_name | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+------------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| CustomData |          0 | PRIMARY  |            1 | Server      | A         |     1073724 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| CustomData |          0 | PRIMARY  |            2 | Plugin      | A         |     1879017 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| CustomData |          0 | PRIMARY  |            3 | ColumnID    | A         |     7516069 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| CustomData |          1 | Cron     |            1 | Plugin      | A         |          20 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| CustomData |          1 | Cron     |            2 | ColumnID    | A         |          20 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| CustomData |          1 | Cron     |            3 | Updated     | A         |     7516069 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| CustomData |          1 | Updated  |            1 | Updated     | A         |     2505356 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
+------------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
```

The cron key is only used every 30 minutes and is not even enabled right now (incase it was brought up)

Comment: Please post all innodb settings from my.cnf !!!

Comment: currentyl i have the same problem with the same kind of query INSERT INTO ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE

Comment: Check this question: [Random write freezes](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/18663/random-write-freezes). You may have to re-evaluate what to use for the clustered index.

Answer (score 4):

You need to make some adjustments in your InnoDB setup

## ADJUSTMENT #1 : Bigger InnoDB Redo Logs

Since I I do not see innodb_log_file_size, I assume you have the default of 5M. Since your innodb_buffer_pool_size = is 4G, you need 1G redo logs.

## ADJUSTMENT #2 : Have InnoDB uses all CPUs

Out of the box, InnoDB does not use all CPUs. I wrote a post long ago about how InnoDB LEFT UNCONFIGURED may work faster in older versions. I also wrote posts about multicore engagement for InnoDB:

- [How do I properly perform a MySQL bake-off?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/3375/how-do-i-properly-perform-a-mysql-bake-off/3376#3376)
- [Is there any performance difference among MariaDB (xtradb plugin) and XtraDB Server for InnoDB?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/16245/is-there-any-performance-difference-among-mariadb-xtradb-plugin-and-xtradb-ser/16246#16246)
- [Percona vs MySQL](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/15595/percona-vs-mysql/15601#15601)
- [Multi cores and MySQL Performance](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/5926/multi-cores-and-mysql-performance/5968#5968)

With these things said, here are the adjustments to make

```
cp /etc/my.cnf /etc/my.cnf_old
```

Add this setting to /etc/my.cnf

```
[mysqld]
innodb_log_file_size = 1G
innodb_io_capacity = 20000
innodb_read_io_threads = 5000
innodb_write_io_threads = 5000
```

Next, run these steps

```
service mysql stop
mv /var/log/mysql/ib_logfile0 /var/log/mysql/ib_logfile0_old 
mv /var/log/mysql/ib_logfile1 /var/log/mysql/ib_logfile1_old
service mysql start
```

Now, all cores with assist InnoDB and there is much more room for transaction isolation

Give it a Try !!!

Comment: sorry for the delay. Didn't seem to help too much but thank you. Still banging my head over this, I've updated the main question some more if you could take another look? :)

Answer (score 1):

How much RAM?  innodb_buffer_pool_size should be about 70% of *available* RAM.

How often are you doing the SELECTs?  The INSERTs?

Note that the INSERTs are also executed on the Slave.  Are you using SBR? or RBR?

PLEASE use SHOW CREATE TABLE; DESCRIBE is less descriptive!

It looks like you have indexes on the fields you are potentially changing.  This is probably part of the problem.  Can you do without some of the indexes?

In particular, let the cron key take longer -- do only (pluginID, columnID)

When Updated is changed, a 'row' in the index must be deleted from one place, and reinserted in another.

Comment: Maybe better to get rid of the cron index altogether? Cardinality of 20 in the 1st and 2nd columns is far too low to be useful and my be harmful.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue on my database.  I had a table that was constantly being updated and used INSERT...ON DUPLICATE KEY.   The updates would take longer and longer and the connections would build up in the queue until mysql crashed.  I tested innotop, instat, reinstalled and restored the tables from a snapshot and nothing worked.

Finally I tracked down the problem to a table (the one that was hogging all the connections).  The primary key was setup as a int(11) which is a signed 32-bit number.  The AUTO_INCREMENT had hit the maximum of 2147483647.  You can determine this by using SHOW CREATE TABLE like so:

```
CREATE TABLE `remote_ip_backoff` (
  `remote_ip_backoff_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `created_time` datetime NOT NULL,
  `modified` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `deleted_time` datetime NOT NULL,
  `is_deleted` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `remote_ip_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `backoff_rule_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`remote_ip_backoff_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `remote_ip_id` (`remote_ip_id`,`backoff_rule_id`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2147483647 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

So inserts that updated the index worked fine, but inserts that tried to add a new row failed (actually they were added with the same auto-increment id)!

You can solve this problem by either truncating the table (effectively resetting the auto_increment counter) or by increasing the primary key to using a BIGINT

```
ALTER TABLE `remote_ip_backoff` MODIFY `remote_ip_backoff_id` BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

The SIGNED BIGINT maximum size is 9223372036854775807 and the UNSIGNED BIGINT maximum size is 18446744073709551615 (or 8 billion times larger than a SIGNED INT)!

SOLUTION: Check your tables' auto-increment counter.  If you are using INTs, then you may have hit their max counter size.

Comment: The table in question has a 3-column primary key and no mention of auto incremented column.