# Mysql settings for query_cache_min_res_unit

Tags: mysql

What is the best setting for `query_cache_min_res_unit` for these results:

```
+-------------------------+-----------+
| Variable_name           | Value     |
+-------------------------+-----------+
| Qcache_free_blocks      | 35327     |
| Qcache_free_memory      | 295242976 |
| Qcache_hits             | 236913188 |
| Qcache_inserts          | 49557287  |
| Qcache_lowmem_prunes    | 0         |
| Qcache_not_cached       | 7128902   |
| Qcache_queries_in_cache | 195659    |
| Qcache_total_blocks     | 426870    |
+-------------------------+-----------+
```

Do I need to change any other settings?

My website creates very large results. This is the current setting:

```
query_cache_min_res_unit = 4096
```

### Info on the mysql dev website

If most of your queries have large results (check the `Qcache_total_blocks` and `Qcache_queries_in_cache` status variables), you can increase performance by increasing query_cache_min_res_unit. However, be careful to not make it too large (see the previous item).

Comment: If your database is suffering from some problem, why not change a parameter you think may help and monitor to see if the problems have eased? If so, then try altering it some more and carry on until the performance no longer improves. Then try modifying another parameter. If ever the performance gets worse, try changing the parameter the other way, or restore it to its original value and try another.

Comment: Database tuning involves some king of dark magic. There is no "correct" value for any setting (otherwise the MySQL folks would have made the engine tune itself automagically). It is up to you to find the right setting for your specific database.

Comment: Try using Domas' [query_cache tuner](http://dom.as/2009/07/08/query-cache-tuning/).

Answer (score 2):

## Observations

- Your question says you have 426870 for `Qcache_total_blocks`. Since each block is 1K, blocks are aligned to the nearest multiple of 1024. Thus, your query cache has about 417M.
- If you divide `Qcache_not_cached` (7128902) by `Qcache_inserts` (49557287), this shows that about 14.4% (1 out of 7) of your queries could not be cached.
- (`Qcache_total_blocks` (426870) - `Qcache_free_blocks` (35327)) / `Qcache_queries_in_cache` (195659) = 2K
- On average, each query cache result hold about 2K, which is theoretically not possible. This could indicate some fragmentation in the query cache.

## Recommendations

- You need a bigger value for [**query_cache_size**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_query_cache_size) (perhaps 2G). If you are using InnoDB, you may get some performance increase if you disable the query cache altogether by setting [**query_cache_size**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_query_cache_size) to 0.
- You need a smaller value for [**query_cache_min_res_unit**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_query_cache_min_res_unit) (minimum value is 512 (0.5K)) if you want to hold small result sets.
- You need a bigger value for [**query_cache_limit**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_query_cache_limit) if you want to cap how big a result is too big.
- See my earlier post : [Is the overhead of frequent query cache invalidation ever worth it?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/23699/is-the-overhead-of-frequent-query-cache-invalidation-ever-worth-it/23727#23727)