# High average load due to the High mysql cpu usage

Tags: mysql, innodb, monitoring, load

i've got 2 warnings about my average load being high in the past week and apparently it has to do something with the mysql

my daily visit has been increased about 10-20 thousand (total of 180-150 thousand pre day ) also i've started to use triggers since last month

my tables are not that big , big ones are about 100,000 rows .

so here is the warning :

```
 This is an automated message notifying you that the 5 minute load average on your system is 10.93.
This has exceeded the 10 threshold.

One Minute      - 40.6
Five Minutes    - 10.93
Fifteen Minutes - 4.78

top - 20:33:02 up 22 days, 22:38,  0 users,  load average: 40.60, 10.93, 4.78
Tasks: 667 total,  83 running, 580 sleeping,   0 stopped,   4 zombie
Cpu(s): 18.5%us,  0.4%sy,  0.0%ni, 80.7%id,  0.1%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.3%si,  0.0%st
Mem:  32840004k total, 32478112k used,   361892k free,   364564k buffers
Swap:  1050616k total,   532240k used,   518376k free, 22111016k cached

 PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
7577 mysql     20   0 6680m 1.4g 5680 S 243.8  4.6  13448:23 /usr/sbin/mysqld --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --plugin-dir=/usr/lib64/mysql/plugin --user=mysql --log-error=/var/lib/mysql/ns4008353.ip-198-27-68.net.err --open-files-limit=7296 --pid-file=/var/lib/mysql/ns4008353.ip-198-27-68.net.pid                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
1296 apache    20   0  262m  72m 7076 R  7.0  0.2   3:55.66 /usr/sbin/httpd -k start -DSSL
```

another one :

```
One Minute      - 73.75
Five Minutes    - 18.41
Fifteen Minutes - 6.96

top - 11:09:03 up 14 days, 13:14,  0 users,  load average: 73.75, 18.41, 6.96
Tasks: 483 total, 111 running, 369 sleeping,   0 stopped,   3 zombie
Cpu(s): 18.2%us,  0.4%sy,  0.0%ni, 81.1%id,  0.1%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.3%si,  0.0%st
Mem:  32840004k total, 32671524k used,   168480k free,   378116k buffers
Swap:  1050616k total,   428900k used,   621716k free, 22453492k cached

 PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
7577 mysql     20   0 7391m 2.2g 5644 S 355.7  6.9   8113:40 /usr/sbin/mysqld --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --plugin-dir=/usr/lib64/mysql/plugin --user=mysql --log-error=/var/lib/mysql/ns4008353.ip-198-27-68.net.err --open-files-limit=7296 --pid-file=/var/lib/mysql/ns4008353.ip-198-27-68.net.pid                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
3480 apache    20   0  211m  19m 3708 R  5.0  0.1   0:00.30 /usr/sbin/httpd -k start -DSSL
```

obviously there is something wrong with mysql

when i do `top` in the ssh , occasionally i see mysql cpu usage goes up to 90%-110% (1 core out of 8 of curse) even when there is not much traffic on the site .

so i did a `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST` and here is the result

```
Id      User                Host        db         Command  Time    State                   Info
387971  sitedb_main     localhost   sitedb_main     Sleep   72      NULL
388070  sitedb_main     localhost   sitedb_main     Query   0      Copying to tmp table     SELECT * FROM `images` WHERE `confirm` = 1   AND `...
388071  sitedb_main     localhost   NULL            Query   0       NULL                    SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST
```

another one :

```
Id      User                Host        db         Command  Time    State           Info
209521  sitedb_main     localhost   sitedb_main     Sleep   108                     NULL
209752  sitedb_main     localhost   sitedb_main     Sleep   0                       NULL
209756  sitedb_main     localhost   sitedb_main     Query   0     Sorting result    SELECT *    FROM (`images`)    WHERE `confirm` =  1
209757  sitedb_main     localhost   NULL            Query   0     NULL              SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST
```

there is one particulars process which has `sleep` under the `Command` column , it starts at 0 for time and goes up to 100 or 200 sometimes 300 and then fades away .

it seems that mysql load peaks when couple of these sleep process (5-6) are running simultaneously

i've no idea what are these sleeping processes (nothing under the info column )

my databes is indexed and my queries are fairly optimaized 
so any suggestion ?

btw i've enabled the slow query log (i hope ) and am in the process of installing mytop :

[problem installing mytop , need a up to date tools for monitoring mysql](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/52422/problem-installing-mytop-need-a-up-to-date-tools-for-monitoring-mysql)

```
Processor Name  Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E3-1245 V2 @ 3.40GHz
Total Memory    32840004 kB
Free Memory 10416752 kB
Total Swap Memory   1050616 kB
Free Swap Memory    1050616 kB
MySQL 5.5.31    Running
```

this is all the lines with innodb ! from my.cnf :

```
innodb_file_per_table=1
innodb_buffer_pool_size=1G
#innodb_log_file_size=256M
#innodb_log_buffer_size=4M
```

my.cnf :

```
bind-address=127.0.0.1
innodb_file_per_table=1
innodb_buffer_pool_size=1G
default-storage-engine=MYISAM
#innodb_log_file_size=256M
#innodb_log_buffer_size=4M
#datadir=/var/lib/mysql
#socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
skip-external-locking
wait_timeout=1200
query_prealloc_size=16384
query_cache_type=1
sort_buffer_size=2M
key_buffer=128M
key_buffer_size=512M
max_connect_errors=10
query_cache_size=128M
read_buffer_size=8M
join_buffer_size=64M
table_cache=1500
max_connections=450
query_cache_limit=4M
max_allowed_packet=128M
tmp_table_size=128M
max_heap_table_size=128M
connect_timeout=10
myisam_sort_buffer_size=64M
thread_cache_size=64
query_alloc_block_size=16384
local-infile=0

open_files_limit=7296
slow-query-log = 1
slow-query-log-file = /var/log/mysql/log-slow-queries.log
long_query_time = 1
```

Comment: Please post your my.cnf's InnoDB settings in the question.

Comment: @RolandoMySQLDBA thanx , i've added my.cnf on the bottom

Answer (score 2):

Looking at this my.cnf, InnoDB for MySQL 5.5 has more firepower you can configure.

I would add the following settings:

```
innodb_read_io_threads=64
innodb_write_io_threads=64
innodb_fast_shutdown=0
innodb_log_buffer_size=256M
innodb_log_file_size=512M
innodb_flush_method=O_DIRECT
query_cache_size=0
```

What are these for?

- [**innodb_read_io_threads**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_read_io_threads) and [**innodb_write_io_threads**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_write_io_threads) (both since MySQL 5.1.38) allocate the specified number of threads for reads and writes. Default is 4 and maximum is 64.
- [**innodb_fast_shutdown**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_fast_shutdown) set to 0 completely purges transactional changes to disk. This also makes for a faster startup.
- [**innodb_log_file_size**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_log_file_size) is 5MB by default in MySQL 5.5. I am merely suggesting they be much bigger. The documentation says : The size in bytes of each log file in a log group. The combined size of log files cannot exceed 3.99999999068677 GB which is equal to the 4294967295 range limit. A pair of 2047 MB log files, for example, would allow you to approach the range limit but not exceed it. The default value is 5MB. Sensible values range from 1MB to 1/N-th of the size of the buffer pool, where N is the number of log files in the group. The larger the value, the less checkpoint flush activity is needed in the buffer pool, saving disk I/O. But larger log files also mean that recovery is slower in case of a crash.
- [**innodb_flush_method**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_flush_method) tells InnoDB to bypass caching anything in the OS. All needed caching is done internally (within the InnoDB Architecture)
- [**query_cache_size**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_query_cache_size) is set to 128M. It shoudl be 0 because InnoDB checks the query cache very frequently. In fact, it's preferred that this be disabled for InnoDB (See my earlier post from Sep 05, 2012 : [Is the overhead of frequent query cache invalidation ever worth it?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/23699/is-the-overhead-of-frequent-query-cache-invalidation-ever-worth-it/23727#23727))
- [**innodb_log_buffer_size**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_log_buffer_size) set higher decreases Disk I/O.

You are probably running with default log files, so I would do this:

### STEP 01 : Log in to mysql and run this:

```
mysql> SET GLOBAL innodb_fast_shutdown = 0;
```

### STEP 02 : Shutdown MySQL

```
service mysql stop
```

### STEP 03 : Rename InnoDB Log Files

```
cd /var/lib/mysql
mv ib_logfile0 ib_logfile0.bak
mv ib_logfile1 ib_logfile1.bak
```

### STEP 04 : Startup MySQL

```
service mysql start
```

Extra time is needed to recreate the new ib_logfile0 and new ib_logfile1

This should increase InnoDB's overall performance in terms of CPU and Disk Usage

### Give it a Try !!!

As a side point, here is what InnoDB looks like under the hood:

## InnoDB Architecture

[image: InnoDB Architecture]

Comment: thanx just to be clear , nothing is going to happen to my current db stored data  or database structure ?  could you explain a little about `ib_logfile` , what do they exactly log ? you moved/copy these file in the step 3 so why do i need to recreate them ?

Comment: Updated my answer. Just be clear, nothing with happen to the data as long as you do STEP 01 to guarantee a complete flush of anything leftover from InnoDB transactions.

Comment: thank you for such a detailed answer , i hate to bother you but in step 3 why should i rename the old log file to *.bak and recreate a new one ? is it to make some sort of archive/backup instead of just deleting them ?

Comment: You need bigger logs in order to have less checkpoint activity. Should you implement these things and you cannot get mysqld to startup up due to log issues, you could remove innodb_log_file_size from my.cnf, put the old log back and restart mysqld. Some people do this, so I rename the logs rather than delete them. I prefer to delete them, I was just being polite.