# problem installing mytop , need a up to date tools for monitoring mysql

Tags: mysql, installation, monitoring

so i'm trying to installl mytop to monitor the database

i'm following this instruction :
http://www.sohailriaz.com/how-to-install-mytop-a-top-clone-for-mysql/

when i try to install it with yum i get this :

```
yum -y install mytop 

    --> Finished Dependency Resolution
    Error: Package: perl-DBD-MySQL-4.013-3.el6.x86_64 (base)
               Requires: libmysqlclient.so.16()(64bit)
    Error: Package: perl-DBD-MySQL-4.013-3.el6.x86_64 (base)
               Requires: libmysqlclient.so.16(libmysqlclient_16)(64bit)
     You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
     You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

i have mysql 5.5.x installed and apparently

```
libmysqlclient.so.16 is provided by MySQL 5.1 packages
```

i'm certinly not going to downgrade to 5.1 .

so is there anyway around this without downgrade or any majore change ? 
if not is there any other more up to date , free , similar tool ?